# JIRA MyGroovy JQL scripted function for range of versions

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin, jql

I'm trying to write a JQL function that gives back a list of versions to compare against. We have a 4 digit number as technical release version that gets updated in cycles. I need to find all issues fixed after a given number (which is currently installed) and a new number, which will be the new installed version.

I'm using the myGroovy plugin (which is free) in JIRA Server 8.7.1.

The script is named releaseRange

My code does not produce the result I'm looking for (zero results) and I do not know why. The sanity checks work, I get warnings, if the validation fails.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.JiraDataType
import com.atlassian.jira.JiraDataTypes
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.VersionManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchProvider
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.SearchQuery
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.operand.QueryLiteral
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.query.QueryCreationContext
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.validator.NumberOfArgumentsValidator
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser
import com.atlassian.jira.util.MessageSet
import com.atlassian.jira.util.MessageSetImpl
import com.atlassian.query.clause.TerminalClause
import com.atlassian.query.operand.FunctionOperand
import ru.mail.jira.plugins.groovy.api.jql.ScriptedJqlValuesFunction

class ReleaseRange implements ScriptedJqlValuesFunction {

    @Override
    public JiraDataType getDataType() {
        return JiraDataTypes.VERSION;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinimumNumberOfExpectedArguments() {
      return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageSet validate(ApplicationUser searcher, FunctionOperand operand, TerminalClause terminalClause) {
        def i18n = ComponentAccessor.getI18nHelperFactory().getInstance(searcher)
        def numberValidMessage = new NumberOfArgumentsValidator(2i, i18n).validate(operand);
        if (numberValidMessage.hasAnyErrors()) {
            return numberValidMessage
        }
        def messageSet = new MessageSetImpl();
        def from, until;

        try {
            from = operand.getArgs().get(0).toInteger();
        } catch (any) {
            messageSet.addErrorMessage("no valid technical release number:${operand.getArgs().get(0)}");
            messageSet.addErrorMessage("${any}");
        }

        try {
            until = operand.getArgs().get(1).toInteger();
        } catch (any) {
            messageSet.addErrorMessage("no valid technical release number:${operand.getArgs().get(1)}");
            messageSet.addErrorMessage("${any}");
        }

        if (from >= until) {
          messageSet.addErrorMessage("from version needs to be less than until version");
        }

        return messageSet;
    }

    List<QueryLiteral> getValues(QueryCreationContext queryCreationContext, FunctionOperand functionOperand, TerminalClause terminalClause) {
        def versionManager = ComponentAccessor.getVersionManager();

        def List<QueryLiteral> literals = new LinkedList<>();
        def from = functionOperand.getArgs().get(0).toInteger();
        def until = functionOperand.getArgs().get(1).toInteger();
        while (from < until) {
          from++;
          literals << new QueryLiteral(functionOperand, versionManager.getVersion(10800, from.toString()).getId().toLong());
        }

        return literals;
    }
}
```

The query

```
fixVersion in releaseRange(2279, 2291)
```

is accepted, but does not produce any result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the getVersion did not work as I expected, using getVersionsByName solved the issue. The code needed to be adapted like that:

```
       while (from < until) {
          from++;
          def versions = versionManager.getVersionsByName(from.toString());
          versions.each{ version ->
             literals << new QueryLiteral(functionOperand, version.getId().toLong());
       }
```